# how to see method's receiver when there are double

Tags: go

I am trying to understand this example.
Is Ccc method of aaa OR bbb or aaa.bbb().

When I go to github, and click on Ccc, I see bunch of Definitions and it's very inconvenience not knowing where to look.

ans := aaa.Bbb().Ccc()

Real example
https://github.com/CyCoreSystems/ari/blob/master/_examples/play/main.go

```
sub := cl.Bus().Subscribe(nil, "StasisStart")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Real example https://github.com/CyCoreSystems/ari/blob/master/_examples/play/main.go
> sub := cl.Bus().Subscribe(nil, "StasisStart")

In this example

`cl` is `Client` struct that implementing `Client` interface that has `Bus()` method.

`Bus` method signiture under `Client` interface is:
`Bus() Bus`

Therefore `cl.Bus()` return some implementation of `Bus` interface.

`Bus` interface is encapsulate `Subscriber` interface that has the following method:

`Subscribe(key *Key, n ...string) Subscription`

That's why you can access to `Subscribe(..)` method if you have `Bus` interface in your hands

I hope I helped to understand the "real example"

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to understand this example. Is Ccc method of aaa OR bbb or aaa.bbb().

`Ccc()` is a method of whatever type `Bbb()` returns. This code:

```
ans := aaa.Bbb().Ccc()
```

Is the same as this code:

```
temp := aaa.Bbb()
ans := temp.Ccc()
```